# Automatically concatenating OR regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, concatenation

I have a PHP array like so (comes from a MySQL database, YouTube is just an example):

```
[regexpr] => array(4) (
   [0] => (string) http://*.youtube.com/v/*
   [1] => (string) https://*.youtube.com/v/*
   [2] => (string) http://youtu.be/*
   [3] => (string) http://m.youtube.com/watch*
)
```

Now, what I am trying to achieve is to find *any* of the matches in a URL (in this case: checking if the URL is a valid YouTube URL).

What I have tried is the following:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($regexpr); $i++)
   $regexpr[$i] = preg_quote($regexpr[$i]); // because of the URLs

$expr = '/(('. implode('|', $regexpr) . '))/i'; // Concatenating the ORs

$found = preg_match($expr, 'http://www.youtube.com/[foo]&v=MyVidID', $matches);
```

However, unfortunately, I was unable to successfully concatenate these expressions - I am not getting any successful "hits".

Would anyone have a pointer as to how to solve this issue?

¡Gracias!

Comment: Post your `$expr` in every `for` iteration, and better output of `preg_quote($regexpr[$i]);` too.

Comment: @webbandit: the for() has no brackets, so it only contains the preg_quote line.

Comment: Oh. I see. `preg_quote($regexpr[$i]);` in every for iteration and `$expr`.

Comment: Yes, it simply contains the escaped expressions which I am trying to concatenate into one expression so that I don't have to loop a preg_match().

Comment: Post your output of `var_dump(preg_quote($regexpr[$i]));` and `var_dump($expr);` for us to be more informated about your problem. We can't test regexp'es without complete patterns.

Comment: fyi- there's a maximum pcre pattern length of a little over 65k bytes. I hit it once doing this type of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is your source "regexs":

```
http://*.youtube.com/v/*
       ^---            ^---
```

the asterisks are "zero or more of the previous" character, not general wildcards. So you're causing the `/` chars to be made optional. What you want is probably `.*`, which is a "zero or more of ANY character"

However, you're passing those through preg_quote, and that'll escape **ANY** regex metacharacters, so in effect you're not passing in ANY wildcards. You're passing in literal asterixes, literal periods, etc...

You should escape the regexes yourself and skip the preg_quote stage, e.g.

```
http:\/\/.*\.youtube.com\/v\/.*
```

Comment: Oh yes, you're absolutely right - I was also escaping the asterisks (not helpful!). Thank you for pointing that out. Your suggestion did the trick - thank you!

Edit: I solved it by escaping the string and then "manually" reversing the escaped asterisks. This way it still works automatically.

Answer (score 2):

what if you parse the urls and then compare them to a white list?  Something like:

```
$myurls= array('http://example.com', 'http://foo.com/', 'http://mysite.com/', 'http://youtube.com?feeble=2&blob=ixls');
$whitelist=array('foo.com', 'youtube.com');

foreach($myurls as $url){
    $parsed=parse_url($url);
    if(in_array($parsed['host'],$whitelist)) echo "$url OK";
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best idea.  Just provide an array of domain names and use PHP's parse_url function

Comment: Yes, this would work - thank you very much. However, these regex-pattern components already exist, so I am trying to reuse them instead of re-doing it via checking a domain whitelist. Thanks however! :-)